# How I could transform this into product over primes :$s_p$= $\frac{1}{2^2-1}+\frac{1}{2^3-1}+....\frac{1}{2^p-1}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, direct-sum, perfect-numbers

1)Can I transforme this sum into product OVER primes:$s_p$= $\frac{1}{2^2-1}+\frac{1}{2^3-1}+....\frac{1}{2^p-1}$ ?

Note : p is prime number and ${2^p-1}$ is prime

2)I would be interest to  know for which values of $p$ that  let us  turn $s_p$ as a product over prime ?

Comment: Let see if I understanding, for $p=3$ we have $s_3=\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{7}=\dfrac{10}{3\cdot7}=\dfrac{2\cdot5}{3\cdot7}$, so do you transform that sum into a product of primes just like the last ones?

Comment: Every rational number has a factorization into prime powers. However most general expressions will not admit an accompanying generic prime factorization for all the values it can take. Indeed, multiplication and addition generally do not play nice together (which is why the Goldbach and twin primes conjectures are so hard). So unless you have a very good reason to *expect* that sum to be have a "generic prime factorization," the answer is likely no for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Some other things to clear up: (i) This has nothing to do with direct sums. (ii) Do the exponents go $2,3,4,5,6,\cdots,p$ or do they go $2,3,5,7,11,\cdots,p$? (iii) How are perfect numbers relevant? We know $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ is perfect for prime $p$, but I am not clear on how that is connected to the sum.

Comment: @blue ,$ 2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ is even perfect  if and only if$(2^p-1)$ is prime, but in the question $(2^p-1)$  is not necessary prime , and this sum may have a relation to zeta function .

Comment: You failed to answer either of my questions: how do the exponents go, and how are perfect numbers relevant (since you used that tag on the question).

Comment: for your first question Imagine that you would be like to write the sum of zeta function as euler product , how you can doing it ?,suppose that (2^p-1) is prime for each p $prime$ and $\frac{1}{(2^2-1)^s}+\frac{1}{(2^3-1)^s}+....\frac{1}{(2^p-1)^s}$,where s is a complex variable , then we could turn it to the euler product , my problem I seek to write it in the general case where :(2^p-1) is not prime .

Comment: Primes are integers, so products of primes are integers, but your sum is not an integer. Therefore, you cannot transform your sum into a product of primes. What do you really want to know? Please edit your question so it asks what you actually mean to ask.

Comment: @GerryMyerson , zeta function defined as sum of non integer , how we could transform it into euler product (product of primes)  ?

Comment: The Euler product for the zeta function is *not* a product of primes. It is a product *over* primes, of an expression *involving* primes, but it is most definitely not a product of primes. In Mathematics, we can say what we mean, rather than say something sorta kinda similar to what we mean. May I repeat my suggestion that you edit your question so it says what you actually mean to say.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sorry in the fact i mean the product over primes ,and I would be interest to know the relation of this sum to zeta function .

Comment: and i think to turn it into product over primes , should be know for which values of $p$ that $(2^p-1)$  to be prime

Comment: You write above that if it were true that $2^p-1$ is always prime then you could write $$(2^2-1)^{-s}+(2^3-1)^{-s}+\cdots+(2^p-1)^{-s}$$ as an Euler product. How would you do that?

Comment: Does $(2^p-1)$ prime for each values of $p$ ?, and in the question $(2^p-1)$ is not necessary prime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15817/discussion-between-rafik-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat. No, $2^p-1$ is not prime for all prime $p$, and, yes, I recognize that in the question you are not assuming $2^p-1$ is prime. But YOU WROTE in the comment just before my first comment that if $2^p-1$ were prime for all prime $p$ then you could turn that sum into an Euler product, and I'm asking how you do that.

Comment: if I know how, then why i'm asked this question ?*

Comment: If you don't know how, then why did you say that you do know how? Why did you write, "we could turn it to the euler product," if you actually don't know whether or not we could write it as an Euler product?